# Assigning a delimited string to a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Hi I have this requirement:

Pipe delimited text file to a table (TEST) in the SQL db  - yes this is fine

Now i need to group the results based on the primary key and return the result set as a delimited (pipe deliited string) to a variable. This variable is then used as an input parameter to a stored proc which later processes stuff.

for example : select * from TEST where primary KEY val - x, so say i get 2 rows

column1   column2
a           b
c           d

Now the result set needs to get converted to a|b|c|d and stored in a variable say xVar

This XVar is then used as an input paratemer to a stored proc which is fairly straightforward.

But any ides on the first part ... can i achieve this without using say a custom script or an active x component?

Thanks a tonne

Abhi

Comment: I think, without being able to give you a complete solution, that you can achieve this using "WITH XML" option in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The script task or component is the only way you can concantenate values from different rows into a single custom variable.